Supremum of a function with power
Is it true that for a function $f(x): \mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty)$ it holds
$$\sup[f(x)^a] \leq [\sup(f(x))]^a $$
for $a \in (-\infty,+\infty)$?

For $a \ge 0$, you will actually get equality, monotonically increasing and continuous is enough for this (without continuity, the case of the supremum not being attained might not work off the top of my head). For $a < 0$, this is not true, taking something like $f(x) = e^{|x|}$, LHS will be $1$ and the RHS will be $0$. For $a < 0$, the RHS should involve $\inf$ somehow. For the sake of pedantry we should probably specify $f \ne 0$ too.
